# Not running at local when "npm run serve" command in vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I was trying to make some app with vue and installed npm command.

when I run "npm run serve" command, I get the following messages.
It seems that I was supposed to run app at "http://localhost:8080/" and was able to access sample pages, not like "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:" stuff.

is it possible to solve this with changing config file or something ?

```
App running at:
  - Local:   http://x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:8080/
  - Network: http://x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I am supposed to access to http://localhost:8080/ and would get some sample pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your host environment was set to `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0`, you should be able to set the variable in your `bash_profile` like this
`HOST="localhost"`

after that reload the environment with `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: You are welcome, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: sorry. I was not used to posting questions. I accepted answer :)

Comment: I am also having a similar issue. If the `HOST` variable is not present in my `~/.profile` (have no `.bash_profile due to OS) can I just write it in there and the ants keep marching on?

Comment: sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
add this line at the end: HOST="localhost"

Save it then run ,

source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can find an answer to your question here - https://forum.vuejs.org/t/npm-run-serve-is-not-defaulting-to-localhost/88007/13.

In a short:

- Add vue.config.js file in a root (same level as package.json file) if you don't have one
- Add the following settings to vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    public: 'localhost:8080',
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for commenting. 
This approach is reasonable. 
But, I could not access to localhost even though "Network:" was changed. 
( it seems that the person who was on your links also have same trouble with me, and still had trouble in the end).
Thank you so much.