# npm run serve on vue does not serve to localhost

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get a grasp on Vue, because frameworks, frameworks, frameworks. I installed vue with npm using `npm install -g @vue/cli` which worked, then i made my project folder using `vue create myproj`, choosing all default options. When I tried to run with `npm run serve` this was my output:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu:8080/ 
  - Network: http://x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu:8080/
```

Which doesn't connect in browser. As far as I understand, it should have `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` followed by the port numbers. The port is not being used by anything else. I checked my hosts:

```
(base) alan@skynet:~/dev/myproj$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   skynet
```

I followed the steps in this similar question: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/npm-run-serve-is-not-defaulting-to-localhost/88007/13 and added a `vue.config.js` with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    public: 'localhost:8080',
  }
}
```

but it only changed my network. I have not changed my `package.json` or any of the default files that come with `vue create`. I even deleted the directory, uninstalled and reinstalled vue in the same location and that did not resolve. This other SO thread [Not running at local when "npm run serve" command in vue project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242821/not-running-at-local-when-npm-run-serve-command-in-vue-project) was also similar, but I do not have a `.bash_profile` and I'm not sure if I can just throw in `HOST="localhost"` anywhere into my `.profile` file, as I'm relatively new to Linux and don't want to break things. I'm just trying to get the initial setup off the ground so I can move on to actually doing vue stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what I did worked, but it now works. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4081#issuecomment-694904714